# How to compute the gradient of the softmax function w.r.t. matrix?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

> Let us consider the following functions
>
> \begin{equation}
> y = \operatorname{softmax}(z)
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> z = h\cdot W + b
> \end{equation}
>
> where $y, h, W$ and $b$ are $1 \times n$, $1 \times m$, $m \times n$ and $1 \times n$ matrices. Compute $\frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{W}}$.

My efforts:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{W}} =  \frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{z}} \times \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{W}}
\end{equation}

Here $z$ is a vector and $W$ is a matrix so $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{W}}$ will be a 3D tensor.

But $y_i$ is a scalar and $W$ is $m \times n$ matrix so $\frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{W}}$ should be of size $m \times n$.

Please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given
$$\eqalign{
 z &= hW+b \cr
 y &= \operatorname{softmax}(z) \cr
 Y &= \operatorname{Diag}(y) \cr
}$$
Find the differential and gradient of $y$ 
$$\eqalign{
dy &= dz\,(Y-y^Ty) \cr
   &= h\,dW\,(Y-y^Ty) \cr
   &= h\,{\mathbb E}\,(Y-y^Ty):dW \cr\cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial W} &= h\,{\mathbb E}\,(Y-y^Ty) \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product, and  ${\mathbb E}$ is a $4^{th}$ order isotropic tensor with components
$${\mathbb E}_{ijkl} = \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl}$$

Also recall that we are working with row vectors, so $(y^Ty)$ is a matrix, not a scalar product.

$$\eqalign{}$$

$$\eqalign{}$$

Comment: Using index notation @hans answer becomes $$\eqalign{\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial W_{km}}&=h_i{\mathbb E}_{ijkl}(Y_{lm}-y_ly_m)\cr&=h_i(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl})(Y_{lm}-y_ly_m)\cr&=h_k(Y_{jm}-y_jy_m)}$$

Comment: Thanks !! ... It helped a lot...